# How to copy a directory from one path to another?

Tags: c

I have a simple question. How to copy a `directory` from one location to another location in `C`? I searched online but the result that I found was about copying a file. It was not about copying a directory? I don't know how to do it except using the `system()` command. I don't want to do it using the `system()` command. Is there any other original way?

Comment: use `fork` and `execl`

Comment: To copy a directory, you must copy its sub-directory structure and all files in it.  This is non-trivial, and is why programs exist to do it.  Either invoke those, or look at their source code to learn what they are doing.

Comment: Study the principle of recursion. From the console o used to use xcopy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy You could use ShellExecute / spawn and run xcopy with right switches.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Modern C](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). The C standard does not know about directories, check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or some newer draft.

Some opensource libraries, notably [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/), could be useful.

You could either use them, or at least study their source code for inspiration.

On Linux, [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), [opendir(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), [closedir(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html) [nftw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) could be useful.

Of course, for Linux, you need to read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and related documentation.

On Linux, [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) and [GNU findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) is ***[free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)***. **You are allowed to download the source code, study it and improve it.**

And the [`sash` shell](http://members.tip.net.au/%7Edbell/programs/sash-3.8.tar.gz) contains also interesting code. Download the source code then study it. **It is [open source](https://opensource.org/) so you can study it and take inspiration from it**.

You could also use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on a recursive [cp(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) command to understand what is going on.

Read also [inode(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html), [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) and [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) to understand that a file could have more than one file path (or even none, if another [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) did an [unlink(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) on it; see also [flock(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html)).

Comment: I want to do it on Linux

Comment: Then **download existing source code** (with [GNU wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)....), and use [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) to explore it and take inspiration from it. Tell your teacher that you did so!

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely check it out.